# Solving a functional equation of type $f(x)+f(x+a)=h(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, functional-equations

I am trying to find the solution(s) of the functional equation
$$
f(x)+f(x+\gamma)=\frac{1}{(3-2\, \cosh(2x))(3-2\,\cosh(2(x+\gamma))}.
$$
Here $\gamma=\mathrm{arcosh}\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a constant and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It would probably be solvable by Fourier transformation if I were able to calculate the Fourier transformation of the RHS. However, I (and Mathematica) were not able to achieve this due to the poles on the real axis and the infinite number of poles in the complex plane.

Also note that $\cosh(2 (x+\gamma))=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5} \sinh (2 x)+3 \cosh (2 x)\right)$ which did not really help me but might be useful. I'd be thankful for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: You can use instead of the Fourier, the [Mittag-Leffler expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) of meromorphic functions.

Comment: Thank you very much @yarchik. I have not worked with those expansions, yet, but I will try it. If I understand you correctly, you suggest to write the general expansion for $f$ and then compare the expansion of the LHS and RHS. So somehow similar to a series expansion?

Comment: Yes, this was my idea

Comment: Note $\,\gamma=\log(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2).\,$ Also, does the expression $\,f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n r(x+n\gamma)\,$ where $\,r(x)\,$ the rational function on the right side count?

Comment: That seems to be a solution @somos at least I checked that the series converges numerically with Mathematica. Do you have any guesses about uniqueness? The equation stems from a physical problem and from that context I suspected $f(0)$ to be finite. However, if the solution were unique, that could certainly not be the case.

Also note, that I mixed up $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ in the denominator and edited the question, sorry for that confusion.

Comment: It is clear, that I can add any solution of the homogeneous equation, i.e. any function that is antisymmetric wrt. $x=\gamma/2$. Maybe I can somehow construct a solution which is regular at x=0...